# Ruby - Return default value if variable is not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operators

I often encounter the following case: I want to set a variable unless it is present. Of course this can be easily done by doing so:

```
var1 = ""
var1 = "dhiughr" unless var1.present?
```

If it was `nil` this could be done with a simple `||=` operator, but since an empty string is not `nil` it won't work. I have tried reading on Ruby's or operator, which theoretically should work:

```
var1 = "" or "dhiughr"
```

but it doesn't. I expect the second string (right from the operator) to be chosen when the first isn't `present`?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why in your opinion "`or` operator theoretically should work"?

Comment: Is there a way to get a one liner for that expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it this way, using [`Object#presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) method (which comes as extension from `active_support` library):

```
var1 = var1.presence || 'dhiughr'
```

It works as you expect:

```
var1 = ''
var1 = var1.presence || 'dhiughr'
var1
# => "dhiughr"
var1 = 'foo'
var1 = var1.presence || 'dhiughr'
var1
# => "foo"
```

Comment: Why wouldn't he use just `||=` ?

Comment: @scaryguy read the question carefully and you'll get the answer.

Comment: I have no idea. I got 2 down votes for my answer and I deleted it.. People doesn't like others talking about their own vote status I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby empty string is truthy value. See [What's truthy and falsey in Ruby?](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362)

Ruby:

```
var1 = ''
var1 = var1.to_s == '' ? 'dhiughr' : var1
```

With rails:

```
var1 = ''
var1 = var1.blank? ? 'dhiughr' : var1
```